# LIKE com comportamento estranho no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query, operador-like

Eu tenho a seguinte query

```
SELECT p.nome_completo, p.id_pessoa, curr.link_video, prof.nome as nome_profissao, fav.id_favorito as fav_id
FROM candidato as cand
INNER JOIN pessoa as p on (p.id_pessoa = cand.fk_pessoa)
INNER JOIN curriculo as curr on (cand.id_candidato = curr.fk_candidato)
INNER JOIN curriculo_has_profissao as chp on (curr.id_curriculo = chp.fk_id_curriculo)
INNER JOIN profissao as prof on (chp.fk_id_profissao = prof.id_profissao)
LEFT JOIN empregador_has_favorito_curriculo as efc on (efc.fk_id_curriculo = curr.id_curriculo)
LEFT JOIN favorito as fav on (fav.id_favorito = efc.fk_id_favorito)
WHERE prof.nome LIKE '%Abastecedor de Linha de Produção%' OR prof.nome LIKE '%Abastecedor de Máquinas%'
AND curr.fk_status_curriculo = 2
```

A ideia é trazer todos os candidatos quando se busca uma profissão pelo nome. Estou usando o LIKE para caso se busque por `Professor` Retornar todos os tipos de professores cadastrados..

o estranho dessa query é que quando eu realizo ela, retorna um resultado, com a profissão `Abastecedor de Linha de Produção`, mas se eu remover o `OR`, deixando só a primeira clausula do `WHERE`, deveria retornar o mesmo resultado, já que a profissão é a mesma. Mas não, nao retorna nenhum resutlado. Também testei trocar por `'%Abastecedor%'` para ver se retornaria algum resultado, mas também não retornou nada.

Alguma ideia ?

Comment: Pode ser algo relacionado a procedência dos operadores lógicos, tentei colocar as cláusulas do `or` entre parênteses.

Comment: Essa nao é a questao, o problema é que com o `OR` ele acha resultado com a profissao `Abastecedor de Linha de Produção`, assim como na query. O problema é quando deixo apenas o `prof.nome LIKE '%Abastecedor de Linha de Produção%'` deveria retornar um resultado, mas não retorna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A questão é esse AND. Provavelmente seu resultado como 'abastecedor de linha de produção' não possui curr.fk_status... igual a 2.
Quando vc coloca o or, ele intepreta assim:

prof.nome like 'abastecedor..' OR (prof.nome like 'abastecedor' and curr.status = 2)

Tira o and do final e faça o teste.